# Using Social.framework and SLRequest with Field Expansion

Tags: cocoa, facebook-graph-api, frameworks

So far, OS X 10.8.2's **Social.Framework** works great:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends"];
SLRequest *fbRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:params];
```

This properly delivers the list of friends of the `me()` object. Fine!

However, once I try to make use of [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/30/updates-to-the-graph-api/), as follows, the request fails with the error:
*An active access token must be used to query information about the current user*:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@".../friends?fields=cover,picture"];
```

This is surely reasoned by the fact, that the access_token will be appended internally in the Social.framework using st. similar to "?access_token=%@", which will fail in conjunction with the previous **?fields=** usage by myself.

So I wonder whether this is actually a bug of the framework, or whether I'm using it wrongly? I'd really be thankful for any helpful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After contacting Apple directly, this is clearly the answer:
Add the field expansion tags using the GET parameter variable, instead of adding them to the actual URL:

```
SLRequest *fbRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
URL:requestURL
parameters:@{@"fields":@"cover,picture"}];
```

Which is obvious, but I didn't think of that :). I'll let this thread as it is if someone might stumble upon the same problem in future!

Comment: Aaaaaand... you saved my life.

Comment: This is the single most important detail that is left out of every example. You totally saved me hours of work here. I was banging my head against my desk trying to figure out why I was getting the "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user" error when everything seemed like it should be in order. Thanks!!!